# Azure ML workspace notebook MLclient error

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-ml-pipelines

I am follwing this tutorial for [Azure ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-azure-ml-in-a-day?view=azureml-api-2)
via Azure ML studio web and "notebooks" inside it

while invoking MLClient object instance, I am getting below error

```
ws = ml_client.workspaces.get(WS_NAME)
print(ws.location,":", ws.resource_group)
```

Things I have tried

1. Creating terminal inside Azure ML Studio web, but it needs separate compute
2. I can only use serverless spark compute which shows available while running notebooks
3. Local powershell with Az login which authenticated successfully ( not sure if AZ CLI path can be set here and if that will help at studio web notebook executions)

How to resolve this?

```
ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. Attempted credentials:  EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.  ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.    SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.     AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path     AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed  AzureDeveloperCliCredential: Azure Developer CLI could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by not using serverless compute . Basically created new compute in Azure ML and use it while executing notebook